# A few questions about leveling in Final Fantasy 6

Tags: final-fantasy-6

I'm close to the end in Final Fantasy 6, and need to farm a few characters up before facing Kefka.

But here's a few things I would like to know, making the process easier:

- Is there an XP catchup mechanic? Thing like the lowest level character in the party gets more XP
- Does a character that is Dead/Removed from the fight/Inflicted with things like Zombie not get XP?
- Does the number of XP shown as gained at the end of the fight splitted between characters, or is it how much XP each character gained?

Playing on SNES Classic.

Comment: Each one of these can be tested for without much effort, or easily found online.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely leveled "wrong".

FF6's leveling mechanic is interesting.  It is of MASSIVE benefit to hit world of ruin as low level as possible (I've done it at level 7), obtain all characters, grab the end-game esper, and level with the esper equipped.

With this route, you basically end up with all magic users, and maybe a couple guys with max speed.  This setup creates uber powerful characters though, and you will hit 9999 damage using just Fire/Ice/Lit 2.  Edgar setup using max MAG will hit 9999 using Flash.  Cure 1 will heal over 5k HP.  Sabin's MAG based blitz (Aura Bolt, Fire Dance, Air Blade, Bum Rush surprisingly) will all hit 9999.  I had Locke at max speed and he attacks about 5 times per one of my other characters.  You can do so much damage with Ultima that it overflows and heals your enemies instead.

Here is a relevant GameFAQ [guide](https://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/554041-final-fantasy-iii/faqs/59823).

Comment: Yeah I was going in semiblind, so had no idea about this kind of perfect leveling. I hit WoR in low 20ies, and have been going around getting party members and doing side activities before hitting the boss. But I'm not sure you are answering my questions here.